# LibFTDI correct compiling / build [ Raspbian ]

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, raspbian, ftdi

### INTRODUCTION

Hi everyone, I'm making a project in Raspbian (Raspberry Pi3) using the async streaming feature of the [libFTDI library](https://github.com/legege/libftdi).
I first tried to build [one](https://github.com/legege/libftdi/blob/master/examples/find_all.c) of their examples that scans all the ftdi devices inside the Build directory following [this guide](http://developer.intra2net.com/mailarchive/html/libftdi/2013/msg00014.html)  using `cmake` and I run perfectly `./find_all` getting all the FTDI devices, and that's good.

So I wanted to build a custom libFTDI project in another directory by my own and to compile it by the only compiler tool I know: `Gnu C Compiler`.

### PROBLEM

Well, the compiler shows me no errors when I tried to compile out of the Build directory using a code of mine which has an `#include libftdi` with 
`gcc -lusb -lftdi` AND `./find_all` gave me back that there's no device found at all.
At this point I toke exactly the same piece of code inside 'find_all.c AND `./find_all` STILL gave me back that there's no device found at all
Obviously before I ran `gcc` I installed all the libFTDI dependencies via `apt-get install`, to be more specific:

- `build-essential`
- `git-core`
- `cmake`
- `doxygen`
- `libusb`
- `libconfude-dev`
- `swig`
- `python-dev`
- `libboost-all-dev`

### QUESTION

Can anyone help me finding out what's wrong in it?
I'd really like to use this wonderful library.
 I state that I'm a newbie in `cmake` stuff therefore I guess that even if I'm making a custom project (and not an example) using libFTDI most probably I also have to cmake. I should be grateful if someone explained to me how to cmake/build/gcc this library everywhere I want.

Thanks for the attention payed.